# How can I fade in a div on hover with jquery on top of image with animated rollover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code that fades in a rollover image on hover. I also have a div with some text in that I want to hide then fade in when the images change at the same speed. I know how to do both separately, just not sure how to write this as a complete function. Any help appreciated. I would like to show hide with jquery so the text displays if javascript is disabled.

The HTML:

```
<ul id="img_grid1">
    <li>
        <h2 class="bigimghead">Heading 1</h2>
        <img class="off" src="images/img1.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img class="on" src="images/img1over.jpg" alt=""/>
        <div class="copy">
            <p>some text, some text</p>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
h2.bigimghead {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
    font-size: 16px;
    top: 10px;
}

img.off {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

img.on {
    position: absolute;
    left:0; 
    top: 0;
}

ul#img_grid1 li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.copy { z-index: 5000; position: relative; width: 200px; top: 20px; }

.copy p { color: #FFF; }
```

The jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
   $(".copy").css("display","none")
});

$("img.off").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "normal");
$(".copy").fadeIn(500);
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "normal");
$(".copy").fadeOut(500);
});
});
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle to understand it better?

Comment: if I understand your question correct, what you need is a div around both the image and the text and then apply the "on"/"off" classes to the containing div.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that as the images change the text appears. I am not sure why my html was edited both images need to be in one <li></li>. I just need the function to hide then fade the text in as the image changes

Comment: I am trying to make a fiddle but can't login at the moment

Comment: @reinder that won't achieve what I am trying to do. I suppose applying opacity to the copy div so that its no visable by default and but fades in when the image changes on hover. does anyone know how to apply opacity to that div and change it when hoving over img.off

Comment: I have changed the jquery achieved what I wanted I just need to stop it repeating the fadeIn out when the mouse enters and leaves a few times anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fade out the text at the same speed as the image here are two options

**Image Hover Method ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dJuX/4/))**

This method is similar to what you have in your existing code with the addition of hiding all of the copy divs via opacity at the beginning.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.copy').css("opacity", "0");
    $("img.off").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                "opacity": "0"
            }, "normal");
            $('.copy').stop().animate({
                "opacity": "1"
            }, "normal");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                "opacity": "1"
            }, "normal");
            $('.copy').stop().animate({
                "opacity": "0"
            }, "normal");
        }
    });
});
```

**List Item Hover Method ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DRUYj/1/))**

This method assumes you want the animation to occur when you click over the entire list item instead of just the image. This will ensure that if you happen to hover over any items placed absolutely above the image (such as the heading or the copy text), the `mouseleave` handler will not trigger.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.copy').css("opacity", "0");
    $("#img_grid1").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).find("img.off").stop().animate({
                "opacity": "0"
            }, "normal");
            $('.copy').stop().animate({
                "opacity": "1"
            }, "normal");
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).find("img.off").stop().animate({
                "opacity": "1"
            }, "normal");
            $('.copy').stop().animate({
                "opacity": "0"
            }, "normal");
        }
    }, "li");
});
```

**Note:** In both the example, I added some additional style to the images so they would be visible without the source files.

Comment: Hi Ruben, That works but on load the text is displayed. I am trying to have the text hidden and then fade in on mouse enter and fade out on mouse leave. Is this possible with your answer?

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe I updated my answer assuming you want the text to be visible if JS is disabled in the browser. Otherwise, you could just set it in the CSS initially.

Comment: Thank you, that works a treat. I have one little issue now that you might of come across before. The heading one text in the h2 tags has a higher z-index than the images so that it is visable. Problem is when I mouse over the heading the .copy disappears

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe I updated my answer with an alternate method that binds on the `li` elements inside of `#img_grid1`. For this to work, it assumes each of your image sets would be contained within an `li` element.

Comment: @RubenInfrante Thank you thats amazing. I really must give more time to learning java script. I wish there was a way for me to up vote this post more. thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you're setting `absolute` positions on your images but li hasn't relative position.

Second, I think you should check that the event has finished before doing it again :

- add some `delay(500)` to prevent another event to achieve (delay should be equal to animation time `fadeIn(500)` for example)
- add a variable who tells if event is done like this :

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var eventIsRunning = false;
      $("img.off").hover(
          function() {
              if(!eventIsRunning) {
                  eventIsRunning = true;
                  $(this).fadeIn();
                  $('.copy').fadeOut();
                  eventIsRunning = false;
              }

          },function() {
              if(!eventIsRunning) {
                   eventIsRunning = true;
                   $(this).fadeOut();
                   $('.copy').fadeIn();
                   eventIsRunning = false;
              }
          }
      );
  });
  ```